# Stopping an iteration without using `break` in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, foreach, iteration

For example, can this code be rewritten without `break` (and without `continue` or `return`)?

```
import logging

for i, x in enumerate(x):
    logging.info("Processing `x` n.%s...", i)
    y = do_something(x)
    if y == A:
        logging.info("Doing something else...")
        do_something_else(x)
    elif y == B:
        logging.info("Done.")
        break
```

EDIT: Since some people criticize the use of `break` and `continue` inside loops, I was wondering whether Python allowed to write `for` loops without them.  I would say that Python doesn't allow this (and maybe it would go against the "one way to do it" rule).

EDIT2: Commenters have made me notice that `return` could be used instead, but that would not  be a solution, either.

Comment: Yes, but why do you want this?

Comment: Are you requesting a way to rewrite the code without breaking out of the loop control flow? I think the reasoning behind why will greatly improve the quality of the answers you get.

Comment: I have added a clarification.

Comment: The occasional use of `break` or `continue` is not evil.  But if you find yourself writing them in every loop, you may want to reevaluate your design.

Comment: Elena, your code is fine. Forget the nonsense 'some people' will try to straightjacket you with.  You question seems to amount to "can one break a loop without breaking the loop".  If the default implicit behavior is to continue the loop, then "No".  If you are actually asking "Can I hide the break in an auxiliary iterator, then "Yes".

Answer (score 6):

You could always use a function and return from it:

```
import logging

def func():
    for i, x in enumerate(x):
        logging.info("Processing `x` n.%s...", i)
        y = do_something(x)
        if y == A:
            logging.info("Doing something else...")
            do_something_else(x)
        elif y == B:
            logging.info("Done.")
            return # Exit the function and stop the loop in the process.
func()
```

Although using `break` is more elegant in my opinion because it makes your intent clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boolean value to check if you are done. It will still iterate the rest of the loop but not execute the code. When it is done it will continue on its way without a break. Example Pseudo code below.

```
doneLogging = False
for i, x in enumerate(x):
    if not doneLogging:
        logging.info("Processing `x` n.%s...", i)
        y = do_something(x)
        if y == A:
            logging.info("Doing something else...")
            do_something_else(x)
        elif y == B:
            logging.info("Done.")
            doneLogging = True
```

Comment: Combine this with `itertools.takewhile()` and you have a pretty nifty solution.

Comment: @marsh: I think that `doneLogging = False` should be outside the loop. A weird solution, but it does the job.

Comment: @Kevin: I think that using `itertools.takewhile()` with an auxiliary function would be the only acceptable answer, thanks.

Comment: `takewhile` uses a break to stop looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sys.exit()`

```
import logging
import sys

for i, x in enumerate(x):
    logging.info("Processing `x` n.%s...", i)
    y = do_something(x)
    if y == A:
        logging.info("Doing something else...")
        do_something_else(x)
    elif y == B:
        logging.info("Done.")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `break` and `continue` keywords only have meaning inside a loop, elsewhere they are an error.

```
for grooble in spastic():
    if hasattr(grooble, '_done_'):
        # no need for futher processing of this element
        continue
    elif grooble is TheWinner:
        # we have a winner!  we're done!
        break
    else:
        # process this grooble's moves
        ...
```

Anyone who says `break` and `continue` should not be used is not teaching good Python.